# Using Python's Format Specification Mini-Language to align floats

Tags: python, string, mini-language

I read that I can use Python's [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec) to have more control over how strings are displayed. However, I am having a hard time figuring out how to use it to display floats aligned on the decimal point.

For example, say I have the following three lists:

```py
job_IDs = ['13453', '123', '563456'];
memory_used = [30, 150.54, 20.6];
memory_units = ['MB', 'GB', 'MB'];
```

I would like to iterate through these three lists and print

> ```
> Job 13453:   30      MB
> Job 123:    150.54   MB
> Job 563456:  20.6    GB
> ```

So far I have tried:

```py
for i in range(len(jobIDs)):
    my_str = "{item:15}{value:6} {units:3}".format( 
    item='Job ' + job_IDs[i] + ':' , value=str(memories[i]),units=memory_units[i]);

    print my_str
```

which prints:

> ```
> Job 13453:   30      MB
> Job 123:     150.54  MB
> Job 563456:  20.6    GB
> ```

which is almost right, but it does not align the floats around the decimal point. How can I use Python's [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec) to do it the way I need?

Comment: Your `memory_used` list is a list of strings. Typically when you want to print floats in a formatted way, you'll use floats. What you have now is a set of strings, and you want the formatting to understand that it should be treated specially. But maybe that's just in the code you posted here?

Comment: Thanks @MattiasNilsson I have updated my code accordingly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
for i in range(len(job_IDs)):
    print "Job {item:15} {value[0]:>6}.{value[1]:<6} {units:3}".format(item=job_IDs[i]+':', value=memory_used[i].split('.') if '.' in memory_used[i] else (memory_used[i], '0'), units=memory_units[i])
```

Here is how it works:

This is the main part: `value=memory_used[i].split('.') if '.' in memory_used[i] else (memory_used[i], '0')`, which means: if there is a decimal point, split the string as the whole and decimal part, or set the decimal part to 0.

Then in the format string: `{value[0]:>6}.{value[1]:<6}` means, the whole part shifted right, followed by a dot, then the decimal part shifted left.

which prints:

```
Job 13453:              30.0      MB
Job 123:               150.54     GB
Job 563456:             20.6      MB
```

Comment: Thanks @xiaomao. I have never seen an if statement where the command to be executed comes **before** the condition. Do you have any pointers where I can read more about this? Also, what is the role of number `6` in the format string `value[0]:<6`?

Comment: @roseck python's ?:-style syntax is `(true) if (condition) else (false)`. The `<` in `<6` is shift left and `6` is pad to 6 characters.

Comment: -1: Actually this doesn't work if `memory_used` is a list of integers and floats as shown in the OP's question. If it is, a `TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable` occurs.

Answer (score 12):

Here's another implementation based on `.split('.')` idea. It might be more readable. Split on `'.'`, right-align the left part, left-align the right part:

```
width = max(map(len, job_IDs)) # width of "job id" field 
for jid, mem, unit in zip(job_IDs, memory_used, memory_units):
  print("Job {jid:{width}}: {part[0]:>3}{part[1]:1}{part[2]:<3} {unit:3}".format(
    jid=jid, width=width, part=str(mem).partition('.'), unit=unit))
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/RNOL8)

```
Job 13453 :  30     MB 
Job 123   : 150.54  GB 
Job 563456:  20.6   MB
```

Answer (score 4):

In case it helps, here's a similar function I use:

```
def align_decimal(number, left_pad=7, precision=2):
    """Format a number in a way that will align decimal points."""
    outer = '{0:>%i}.{1:<%i}' % (left_pad, precision)
    inner = '{:.%if}' % (precision,)
    return outer.format(*(inner.format(number).split('.')))
```

It allows a fixed precision after the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

This does it:

```
import re

job_IDs = ['13453', '123', '563456']
memory_used = ['30', '150.54', '20.6']
memory_units = ['MB', 'GB', 'MB']

for i in range(len(job_IDs)):
    lh=re.match(r'(\d+)',memory_used[i]).group(1)
    if '.' in memory_used[i]:
        rh=re.match(r'(\d+)\.(\d+)',memory_used[i]).group(2)
        sep='.'
    else:
        rh=''    
        sep=' '


    my_str = "{item:15}{l:>6}{s:1}{r:6} {units:3}".format( 
    item='Job ' + job_IDs[i] + ':' , l=lh,s=sep,r=rh,units=memory_units[i])

    print my_str
```

To get your precise out put, you need to break the strings on the optional '.'

You could also convert those strings to floats.