# python - string tabs working when print in cmd but issue when saving to file

Tags: python, string, windows, file, encoding

Working on Windows 10 with cmd encoding cp852, with code:

```
import time,os,os.path as os_path, sys,psutil

def current_path():
    return os_path.dirname(sys.argv[0])+'\\'

PATH=current_path()

def string_line_spacing(keys,vals=None,newline=True,dashUp=True,dashDown=True):

    print '#'*20
    print keys,vals
    if vals is not None:
        keys%=vals

    keys=keys.split(',')

    ln = len(keys)


    if ln:
        st =(' | '+' \t | '.join(keys)+' \t | ').expandtabs(23)
        print st
    else:
        st=''



    if newline:
        st+='\n'

    if dashUp and dashDown:
        st='-'*len(st)+'\n'+st+'-'*len(st)+'\n'
    elif dashUp and not dashDown:
        st='-'*len(st)+'\n'+st+'\n'
    elif not dashUp and dashDown:
        st+='-'*len(st)+'\n'

    return st

def string_add_dash_line(st,):

    st+='-'*len(st.split('\n')[1])+'\n'

    return st

if 1:
    crosslinesHeaderKey='Line, Boundary, Value'
    parametersHeaderKey='Parameter, Axis, Boundary, Value'
    crosslinesKey='%s, %s, %.3e'
    parametersKey='%s, %s, %s, %.3f'

    lst=[
    ('Centroid', 'X', 'section', 246.31952920482601), 
    ('Centroid', 'X', 'under-water-line', 0.34080500000000002), 
    ('Centroid', 'Y', 'section', 18026.300431234307), 
    ('Centroid', 'Y', 'under-water-line', 55924.037961711911), 
    ('Moment I', 'X', 'section', 268549.26328172954), 
    ('Moment I', 'X', 'under-water-line', 1243239.1468088273), 
    ('Moment I', 'Y', 'section', 870.23365699999999), 
    ('Moment I', 'Y', 'under-water-line', 1780.9078169999998), 
    ('Moment II', 'X', 'section', 54.80712793964701), 
    ('Moment II', 'X', 'under-water-line', 49.460183476832832), 
    ('Moment II', 'Y', 'section', 0.0069228618808385165), 
    ('Moment II', 'Y', 'under-water-line', 0.0082489999999999994), 
    ('Moment II', 'XY', 'section', 47648.175716628961), 
    ('Moment II', 'XY', 'under-water-line', 88021.62478363933), 
    ('Centroid Moment II', 'X', 'section', 6.020399342164886), 
    ('Centroid Moment II', 'X', 'under-water-line', 0.0035209999999999998), 
    ('Centroid Moment II', 'Y', 'section', 18026.342138067019), 
    ('Centroid Moment II', 'Y', 'under-water-line', 55924.159145367004), 
    ('Centroid Moment II', 'XY', 'section', 2882575.6346526803), 
    ('Centroid Moment II', 'XY', 'under-water-line', 5599891.3026070464)]

    annotationKey='SECTION: X=1e5\n'

    st=annotationKey

    st+=string_line_spacing(parametersHeaderKey,None)
    for tup in lst:
        st+=string_line_spacing(parametersKey,tup,True,False,False)
    st=string_add_dash_line(st)
    print sys.getdefaultencoding()
    print st
    open(PATH+'test.txt','w').write(st)
```

From notepad++ while running `%CMD64% /k " %python_27a_CMD_settings% && %python_27a% $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` im getting text with nice formatted tabs:

```
SECTION: X=1e5
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Parameter                   |  Axis                       |  Boundary                   |  Value                      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Centroid                    |  X                          |  section                    |  246.320                    |
 | Centroid                    |  X                          |  under-water-line           |  0.341                      |
 | Centroid                    |  Y                          |  section                    |  18026.300                  |
 | Centroid                    |  Y                          |  under-water-line           |  55924.038                  |
 | Moment I                    |  X                          |  section                    |  268549.263                 |
 | Moment I                    |  X                          |  under-water-line           |  1243239.147                |
 | Moment I                    |  Y                          |  section                    |  870.234                    |
 | Moment I                    |  Y                          |  under-water-line           |  1780.908                   |
 | Moment II                   |  X                          |  section                    |  54.807                     |
 | Moment II                   |  X                          |  under-water-line           |  49.460                     |
 | Moment II                   |  Y                          |  section                    |  0.007                      |
 | Moment II                   |  Y                          |  under-water-line           |  0.008                      |
 | Moment II                   |  XY                         |  section                    |  47648.176                  |
 | Moment II                   |  XY                         |  under-water-line           |  88021.625                  |
 | Centroid Moment II          |  X                          |  section                    |  6.020                      |
 | Centroid Moment II          |  X                          |  under-water-line           |  0.004                      |
 | Centroid Moment II          |  Y                          |  section                    |  18026.342                  |
 | Centroid Moment II          |  Y                          |  under-water-line           |  55924.159                  |
 | Centroid Moment II          |  XY                         |  section                    |  2882575.635                |
 | Centroid Moment II          |  XY                         |  under-water-line           |  5599891.303                |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But in saved file, matplotlib savefig, and console from nppexec using command :

```
npp_save
cd $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)
$(SYS.python_27a_CMD_settings) && $(SYS.python_27a) $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)
```

its get ugly:

[image: ugly formatted tabs]

But when I copy paste it in here its getting formatted properly...

Problem lay in encoding? How to fix it?

Comment: How does it get ugly? Your ``ugly'' version does not look ugly to me.

Comment: First, figure out how to use a fixed width font.  Next, find out how you can adjust how many spaces equals a tab in matplotlib

Comment: this fixed my issue in matplotlib: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22664091/matplotlib-text-alignment