# Python code neither running proper nor showing errors in VS Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

[image: Screenshot of Code & output]I am using Vs code(Charm was not working smoother on my PC)  for python development it stuck after debugging without showing errors or output.

I searched in stack overflow for a matching solution

```
weight = int(input("Enter weight: "))
unit   = input("(K)kilograms or (P)pounds? ")

if unit.upper == "P":
    (weight*=1.6)
    print("Weight in kilograms: " + weight)
else if Unit=="K":
    (weight*=1.6)
    print("Weight in pounds: " + weight)
else:
    print("ERROR INPUT IS WRONG!")
```

I expect it to take input and give converted output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script:

- misses a ()
- uses an unknown name `Unit`
- tries to add string and numbers : `print("Weight in pounds: " + weight)`
- does the pound calculation wrong
- uses () where not applicable
- uses `else if ... :`

---

> ```
> weight = int(input("Enter weight: "))
> unit   = input("(K)kilograms or (P)pounds? ")
>
> if unit.upper == "P":                         # unit.upper()
>     (weight*=1.6)                             # ( ) are wrong, needs /
>     print("Weight in kilograms: " + weight)   # str + float?
> else if Unit=="K":                            # unit  ... or unit.upper() as well
>     (weight*=1.6)                             # ( ) are wrong
>     print("Weight in pounds: " + weight)      # str + float
> else:
>     print("ERROR INPUT IS WRONG!")
> ```

You can simply use `.upper()` directly with your input:

```
# remove whitespaces, take 1st char only, make upper 
unit   = input("(K)kilograms or (P)pounds? ").strip()[0].upper()
```

Even better probably:

```
weight = int(input("Enter weight: "))
while True:
    # look until valid
    unit = input("(K)kilograms or (P)pounds? ").strip()[0].upper()
    if unit in "KP":
        break
    else: 
        print("ERROR INPUT IS WRONG! K or P")

if unit == "P":                          
    weight /= 1.6                           # fix here need divide
    print("Weight in kilograms: ", weight)  # fix here - you can not add str + int
else:  
    weight *= 1.6                        
    print("Weight in pounds: ", weight)
```

You should look into str.format:

```
    print("Weight in pounds: {:.03f}".format(weight))  # 137.500
```

see f.e. [Using Python's Format Specification Mini-Language to align floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549084/using-pythons-format-specification-mini-language-to-align-floats)